# how to create cocos2d-x with box2d project for ios and android combine?

Tags: android, ios, box2d, cocos2d-x

I am cocos2d game developer. 
Now, I want to work with **`cocos2d-x`** to use functionality of multiplatform support.
I had developed few projects with cocos2d-x with box2d for only iOS using xcode.
I had created and worked with simple cocos2d-x project with iOS and android combined. that simple project is works for both ios and android. I have followed **`raywenderlich tutorial`** to create that simple multiplatform project using cocos2d-x framework.

Now my problem is that, I can not create combine project using cocos2d-x framework using box2d for both android and iOS. anybody had do that kind of task?

please, help me for how to create that combine cocos2d-x with box2d project for iOS and android.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using cocos2d-x 2.1 or above you can now use the create_project.py python script available in tools/project-creator.

```
./create_project.py -project MyGame -package com.MyCompany.AwesomeGame -language cpp
```

Both Box2d and chipmunk are included in the project.